# Which schemes are there that we know their structure sheaf?(A formula for structure sheaf)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For affine schemes we know explicitly their structure sheaf I mean that if
$X=Spec(A)$ where A is a ring we know exactly what is
$O_X(U)$ as a set
for $U\subseteq X$  an open set.

Which schemes are there that we know their structure sheaf ?
for example if
$X=A^2-\left\{{(0,0)}\right\}$
what is
$O_X(U)$ exactly?
I know for example if $U=X$ then
$O_X(X)=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$
but I want general information on the arbitrary open set.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? The structure sheaf is part of the data of a scheme - if you have a scheme, you have its structure sheaf, by definition. I think what you're really asking is: If we're given some kind of presentation of a scheme, how explicitly can we understand its structure sheaf? Well, this depends on what kind of presentation you allow. Certainly if you're given a scheme as an explicit gluing of affine schemes, and an open set as an explicit union of affine opens, then there is a formula which describes the value of the structure sheaf on this open set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .Yes I mean this. can you give me that formula or introduce a reference for it? I have never seen such formula And can you answer my special example about $X=A^2-\left\{(0,0)\right\}$?

Comment: @hdd Well we know that $\mathscr O_X(D(f)) = A_f$ when $X = \text{Spec}(A)$. In general we can't say much more about general open sets.

Comment: @NoelLundström Isn't it true that for any open set $U\subseteq \text{Spec}(A) = X$, we have  $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \varprojlim_{D(f)\subseteq U} A_f$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes that is indeed true, thanks for pointing it out! But it's hard to directly compute $\mathscr O_X (U)$ with that formula. There is no closed form for $\mathscr O_X (U)$ for general $U \subset X$ involving only $A$ that I know of. Completely unrelated, how do you make the $O$ in your comment look like that? I type "\mathscr O" but you must use something else?

Comment: @NoelLundström I'm not sure how to make sense of "closed form" in this context.  Certainly a limit in the category of rings has a very concrete description: an element consists of a coherent (with respect to the connecting maps) choice of element from each factor. $\mathcal{O}$ is \mathcal{O}.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I guess "closed form of $Y$" could mean something equivalent to $Y$ but that is much easier to compute, not formally in any way. Kind of how we have a closed form of $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} i$ being $n(n+1)/2$, you could say that $A_f$ is closed form for the expression $\text{colim}_{D(g) \subset D(f)} A_g$. But there is no "closed form" for $\text{colim}_{D(g) \subset U} A_g$ for general $U$.

Comment: Thank you guys. But as I said We know explicitly $O_X(U)$ for an open subset of $X=spec(A)$. It is $(s_p)_{p\in U}$such that for every $p\in U$ ,$s_p\in A_p$ and for every $p\in U$ there is an open subset $p\in V \subseteq U$  and $a,b\in A$ that , $s_q=a/b$ for every q in V  .                                                                                                                                  My question was about not affine schemes like $A^2- \left\{(0,0)\right\}$.

Comment: @NoelLundström : watch out, here it's a limit, not a colimit

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks for pointing that out! @MaximeRamzi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to understand sections of a sheaf over an arbitrary open set in an arbitrary scheme, just think about the sheaf axioms!

Let's say $X$ is covered by affine opens $U_i = \text{Spec}(A_i)$ for $i\in I$. Then for an arbitrary open set $U\subseteq X$, $U$ has an open cover $(U\cap U_i)_{i\in I}$. The sheaf covering condition then defines $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ as the equalizer of the diagram $$\prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i,j\in I} \mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i\cap U_j).$$
That is, to give an element in $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is to give an element in $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i)$ for each $i\in I$, in such a way that these elements agree on their restrictions to the rings $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i\cap U_j)$:

$$\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \{(x_i)_{i\in I}\mid x_i\in \mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i) \text{ and }x_i|_{U\cap U_i\cap U_j} = x_j|_{U\cap U_i\cap U_j}\text{ for all }i,j\in I\}$$

Now for each $i\in I$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i) = \mathcal{O}_{U_i}(U\cap U_i)$, and similarly for $U\cap U_i\cap U_j$ (which is a subset of two affine schemes, $U_i$ and $U_j$) so we've reduced to understanding the value of the structure sheaf on an arbitrary open set of an *affine* scheme.

So let $X = \text{Spec}(A)$, and let $U\subseteq \text{Spec}(A)$ be an open set. The distinguished affine opens $D(f)$ form a basis for the topology on $\text{Spec}(A)$, so $U$ admits a covering $U = \bigcup_{i\in I} D(f_i)$. Again, the sheaf covering condition defines $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ as the equalizer of the diagram $$\prod_{i\in I} \mathcal{O}_X(D(f_i)) \rightrightarrows \prod_{i,j\in I} \mathcal{O}_X(D(f_i)\cap D(f_j))$$
or equivalently: 
$$\prod_{i\in I} A_{f_i} \rightrightarrows \prod_{i,j\in I} A_{f_if_j}.$$
That is, to give an element in $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is to given an element in $A_{f_i}$ for each $i\in I$, in such a way that these elements agree on their maps into the further localizations $A_{f_if_j}$: 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \{(x_i)_{i\in I}\mid x_i\in A_{f_i} \text{ and }x_i = x_j \text{ in }A_{f_if_j}\text{ for all }i,j\in I\}.$$

**Edit:** You suggest the following "explicit" formula for the structure sheaf of an affine scheme: 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(U) \{(s_p)_{p\in U} \mid \text{for every }p\in U, s_p\in A_p \text{ and for every }p\in U, \text{there is an open subset }p\in V\subseteq U\text{ and }a,b\in A\text{ such that }s_q = a/b\text{ for every }q\in V\}.$$

Almost the same formula works for arbitrary schemes. First let's agree that if $s\in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_X$ at the point $p$, and if $p\in V\subseteq X$ is an affine open with $V = \text{Spec}(A)$, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is canonically isomorphic to $A_p$, so we can think of $s$ as being an element of $A_p$. Then: 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(U) \{(s_p)_{p\in U} \mid \text{for every }p\in U, s_p\in \mathcal{O}_{X,p} \text{ and for every }p\in U, \text{there is an affine open subset }p\in V\subseteq U\text{ with }V = \text{Spec}(A)\text{ and }a \in A\text{ such that }s_q = a/1\in A_q\text{ for every }q\in V\}.$$

Both of these formulas can also be proven using the sheaf axioms. They're a different perspective than the formulas I wrote above, but I'd argue that they're not really more or less explicit. It's a question of picking a compatible family of germs vs a compatible family of sections on an open cover.

---

Let's look at the specific case of the affine plane minus the origin. Let $X = \mathbb{A}^2$, and let $X' = \mathbb{A}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Then $X'$ is an open subscheme of $X$, so by definition $\mathcal{O}_{X'}(U) = \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for all open $U\subseteq X'$. So again, understanding the structure sheaf on $X'$ just comes down to understanding the sections on an arbitrary open set in $X$, the affine plane.

One relevant observation here, generalizing the fact that the global sections of $X$ and $X'$ are the same, is that if $U\subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ is open and $U' = U\setminus \{(0,0\}$, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \mathcal{O}_X(U')$.

First, I claim that this is true for any distinguished open $U = D(f)$, with $f\in k[x,y]$. Covering $U'$ as $U' = (U \cap D(x))\cup (U\cap D(y))$, this amounts to showing that if $g_1\in k[x,y,f^{-1},x^{-1}]$ and $g_2\in k[x,y,f^{-1},y^{-1}]$ localize to the same element of $k[x,y,f^{-1},x^{-1},y^{-1}]$, then there is some $g\in k[x,y,f^{-1}]$ which localizes to $g_1$ and $g_2$. This argument is essentially the same as the argument that the global sections of $X'$ are $k[x,y]$.

Now for an arbitrary open $U\subseteq  X$, $U$ is covered by finitely many distinguished affine opens, and $U'$ is covered by these same opens with the origin removed. So we compute both $\mathcal{O}_X(U')$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ as an equalizer of exactly the same diagram of rings, and they're equal.

Incidentally, this result is also an immediate consequence of the "Algebraic Hartogs' Lemma": In a normal Noetherian scheme, if a rational function is regular outside a closed subset of codimension at least two, then it can be uniquely extended to a global regular function.

Comment: Dear Dr Kruckman. Your answer was very complete and very exciting. I enjoyed to read that. Thank you very much. I just cant understand line 9 and sentence <<Now for each $i\in I$,$O_X(U\cap U_i)=O_{U_i}(U\cap U_i)$>>. I don't think so  because if we want to make $U_i$ a scheme we define $(U_i,O_{U_i})=(U_i, O_X|_{U_i})$. but it isn't clear to me why should we have that equality(up).

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}$ is the sheaf on $U_i$ defined so that for any open $V\subseteq U_i$, we have $\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}(V) = \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ (we restrict $\mathcal{O}_X$ to the open subsets of $U_i$, all of which are also open in $X$). Now take $V = U\cap U_i$, which is an open subset of $U_i$, to get the equality $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i) = \mathcal{O}_{X}|_{U_i}(U\cap U_i) = \mathcal{O}_{U_i}(U\cap U_i)$.

Comment: I know this. .But I said it is  just a definition. So you should prove that $O_X|_{spec A_i}=O_{spec A_i}$ to complete your answer. It means proving:   $ O_X(U)=O_{spec A_i}(U)$ for every $U\subseteq spec A_i $ directly.  Does anybody agree to me?

Comment: I think I was so wrong. It is in the definition of scheme.Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, it's part of the definition of "open subscheme". If my answer resolves your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: About my special example, you answer completely. Also you give a good overview about general cases. I want this problem stay open to answer  the general question: For which schemes X we know explicitly what is  $O_X(U)$ for $U \subseteq  X$  open set.

Comment: @hdd To get an answer to this question, you need to make it much more precise (see my first comment under your question). What does it mean to "know explicitly what is $O_X(U)$"?

Comment: As a set. Like affine spaces.

Comment: @hdd Part is the point of my answer is that the  extent to which we understand the structure sheaf of an arbitrary scheme (when it's presented as a gluing of affine schemes) is essentially the same as the degree to which we understand the structure sheaf of an affine scheme. In each case, given an arbitrary open set $U$ we have to compute $O_X(U)$ by covering $U$ by distinguished affine opens and applying the sheaf axioms.

Comment: Can you give an example of a scheme where we "know" the structure sheaf and one where we don't "know" it?

Comment: I think you overestimate the degree to which we "know" the structure sheaf of any affine scheme $X=\text{Spec} A$. For a *distinguished* open $D(f)$, we know $O_X(D(f))= A_f$. But do we really "know" the value of the structure sheaf on  an *arbitrary* open set? If your answer is "yes", then I claim that we also "know" all structure sheaves of all schemes.

Comment: If you have read my previous comments, you actually saw this. I say again:
for an open subset of 
X=spec(A):
$O_X(U)=\left\{(s_p)_{p∈U}:  \text{for every }  p∈U, s_p∈A_p   \text{ and for every } p∈U,\text{there is an open subset }  p∈V⊆U \text{ and }  a,b∈A \text{ that } , s_q=a/b \text{ for every }  q \text{ in } V\right\}$

Comment: .In  Vakil notes  say if we have value of sheaf on  base opens then we can find its value on arbitrary open sets .By this argument and the fact that $ O_X(D(f))=A_f$ we can show  above formula for affine scheme .Schemes  are locally affine so I want know if there is a formula for schemes in general.

Comment: Yes, and almost exactly the same formula works for arbitrary schemes, by almost exactly the same argument. I've added an analogue of your formula to my answer. I've also turned my original descriptions involving open covers into similar looking formulas. @hdd

Comment: I think your answer has a little problem( part 2 formula). Maybe your mean was like this:                                               $O_X(U)=\left\{(s_p)_{p\in U}:\text{ for every } p\in U ,s_p\in O_{X,p} , \text{ for every } p\in U \text{ there are open and affine subsets } p\in V_1\subseteq V_2=spec A\subseteq U \text{ and } a,b\in A \text{ such that } s_q=a/b \text{ for all } q\in V_1   \right\}$

Comment: @hdd There's no need for such complications. Suppose we're in your situation, so we have $p\in V_1\subseteq V_2 = \text{Spec}(A)\subseteq U$ and $a,b\in A$ such that $s_q = a/b$ for all $q\in V_1$. Let $D(b)\subseteq V_2$ be the distinguished open subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$. Then $V_1\cap D(b)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, so we can find an affine open neighborhood $V = \text{Spec}(B)$ with $p\in V\subseteq V_1\cap D(b)$. And $a/b\in \mathcal{O}_X(D(b))$ restricts to an element $c\in \mathcal{O}_X(V) = B$, such that $s_q = c/1 = a/b$ for all $q\in V$. And we're back to my formula.

Comment: The point is that there's no reason to write $s_q = a/b$, since by restricting to a smaller affine open in which $b$ is invertible, we can get $b$ in the denominator. Anyway, it's straightforward to prove that the formula I gave works. You should try it.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you.